# Reference error from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

[test sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0eJu.png)
[Jayce sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POdXY.png)

I have 2 sheets: **test** and **Jayce**.

On **test** sheet, I have a table with a total with contains a sum equation. Once I hit a submit button, the info is supposed to copy/paste the data into **Jayce** sheet after comparing the date selected so the value can be put into the correct cell.

I don't get why I keep getting a `#ref!` error.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
'Sheet1(test)
'Sheet5(Jayce)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim dateRange As Range
Dim dateSelected As Date: dateSelected = Sheets(2).Range("Q5").Value
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("test")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Jayce")
Dim counterCopy As Range: Set counterCopy = Sheets(2).Range("M2")

For Each dateRange In Sheets(6).Range("B5:B370")
    If dateRange >= dateSelected And dateRange <= dateSelected Then
        counterCopy.Copy Destination:=Sheets(6).Range("D" & dateRange.Row)

        Sheet5.Range("D" & dateRange.Row).Style = "Normal"
        'ws.Range("G2:L19").ClearContents 'clear contents of table
    End If
Next
    MsgBox "done"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your data?

Comment: Lucas, I have added 2 hyperlinks since stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post screenshot yet due to my reputation

Comment: I'd suggest moving the `Dim dateSelected` line to below the `Dim ws2` line. Possibly change `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook` so it always points to the workbook containing the code. Change all occurrences of `Sheet(2)`, `Sheet(6)` and `Sheet5` to `ws` or `ws2`; you've set references to the relevant worksheets so might as well use them. As @T4roy says you might have a problem with the date. Maybe change `dateSelected` to a range reference.

Comment: Your `If` line is a bit confusing. Isn't it the same as saying `If dateRange = dateSelected`?  `dateRange` can't be bother higher AND lower than `dateSelected`. It can be equal - be careful of the time element of the date though.

Comment: Does the cell you're copying contain a formula?  It will paste the formula to the new destination which may then reference an invalid cell. E.g A formula in column B that references column A will get a `#REF!` error if copied to column A as it's trying to reference off the sheet. Remove the `Destination` part of the line and use `PasteSpecial` on a new line to paste the values.

Comment: hey darren, yeah my cell contains a sum formula which i figured out that its the main problem that is causing for the #ref! error. thank you for taking the time, appreciate it!

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, i made a few fix onto the code. i tried to convert the Range reference to compare 2 dates. However I am still getting a ref error. My cell that I am refering has a sum formula which i think that is the problem. How can I have excel to copy paste the Total?

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook, I have resolved the issue. It is not onto the datatype comparison, but it was a pasting value problem, in which I used the function Paste:=xlValues  in order to get the job done. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be with this If statement, it is comparing datatype `Range` with datatype `Date`

`If dateRange >= dateSelected And dateRange <= dateSelected Then`

Also I would check how you are referencing your sheets as you are using Indexes 2 & 6 and names 'test' and 'Jayce', try keeping to 1 referencing type.